# Rails not detecting Node.JS

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Im having an issue while trying to solving another one.

Im developping a Rails app on Windows 10, I run into the JavaScript issue that avoid Rails from working, a lot of people solve this issue by Installing Note.JS, some others change UTF-16LE to UTF-8 on routines.rb on ExecJS gem.

None of those solve my issue so I decide to force Rails using Node.JS instead of Windows default JScript by installing Node.JS (I tried with both x64 and x86 versions) and adding

```
ENV['EXECJS_RUNTIME'] = 'Node'
```

to my boot.rb ... this drive my into my second error by showing this message on rails server loading process:

> There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
>   Gem Load Error is: Node.js (V8) runtime is not available on this system

I really appretiate your help! Im driving with those error for a while now and I feel kind of stuck now.